# C++ cout giving unexpected with dereferenced pointer

Tags: c++

So, I have a function which returns a pointer to a dynamically allocated double, and I need to print the value to which it points (silly I know).

```
double * ans1p = dot(v1, v2);
    double ans1 = *ans1p;
    cout << "Answer to problem 1:" << endl;
    cout << ans1 << endl;
    cout << *ans1p << endl;
```

The first cout statement returns the expected value.

The second returns something random and unexpected. What's the difference? It seems to be that in both cases what's being printed is the value pointed to by ans1p.

I'd rather eliminate ans1 and its cout statement entirely.

OK, here is the dot function:

```
double * dot(Vector &v1, Vector &v2) {
if (getLength(v1) != getLength(v2) ) {
    std::cout << "Error: cannot perform dot product. Vectors must be " <<
        "equal length." << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
double result = 0;
for (unsigned int i = 1; i <= getLength(v1); ++i) {
    result += (v1.elements[i] * v2.elements[i]);
}
double * resultPtr = new double;
resultPtr = &result;
return resultPtr;
}
```

For the record, I wouldn't attempt to do it this way, but it's part of an assignment. And I'm supposed to return the 0 pointer in the event of mismatched sizes.

OK, looking at it, I can see that result is out of scope when the function returns, and the pointer I'm returning just points there (right?). But then, I can't think of how to do what I want to do.

I suppose I could declare a double pointer outside the function, pass the pointer as an argument, and set it inside the function. But I'd kind of like to figure out how to do it the way I planned. Although, thinking about it, it might be better to do it this way once I understand what's going on with the old way, right?

Comment: As you can see [here](http://ideone.com/7OzP5), the problem isn't in that very small code snippet you included.

Comment: What is the implementation of `dot`? it looks like it returns a pointer to deallocated stack space.

Comment: from the symptoms, it sounds as if `dot` returns a pointer to some automatic variable (non-static local variable). then the pointer is invalid and is known as a **dangling pointer**. if that's the case, then if it works for computing `ans1`, then that's because at that time the memory area of the automatic variable has not yet been reused; and if it doesn't work for output of `*ans1p`, then that's because by now that memory has been reused. But this is all hypothesis. Show the code, dammit!

Comment: Yep, it's what we all thought. @AlfP.Steinbach or @Dani post an answer. For a quick fix, change `resultPtr = &result;` to `*resultPtr = result;` but wait for one of them to provide an in-depth explanation and why this is bad design on many levels.

Comment: "Error: cannot perform dot product. Vectors must be equal length": Since when? The dot product is defined for *all* vectors, not just equal length ones. Also, you should never rely on floating-point equality the way you do in your test.

Comment: @Nicol: Chances are, `getLength` returns the dimensionality of the vector, not its magnitude.  So there's no floating point equality checks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's your problem right there:

```
double * resultPtr = new double;
resultPtr = &result;
return resultPtr;
```

You allocate a new `double` on the heap... then assign the address of a local variable to `resultPtr`. You get a memory leak (what was allocated with `new double` is lost), and you then return the address of said local variable. That's *undefined behavior*. Which means anything can happen.

To fix this, you must change the assignment to actually *use* the memory you just allocated:

```
double * resultPtr = new double;
*resultPtr = result; // assign the value to the value pointed to resultPtr
return resultPtr;
```

Or, better yet:

```
return new double(result);
```

---

*Considering the OP* has *to use a pointer, then this is irrelevant. Left as a bonus (and because I wrote this anyway, deleting it would be a waste).*

Or you could also drop the whole memory allocation and return `result`. `double`s are pretty light, and I really don't see why you absolutely *must* return a pointer rather than the value itself:

```
double dot(Vector &v1, Vector &v2) {
    // check here and throw an exception if needed instead of returning 0

    double result = 0.0;
    for (unsigned int i = 1; i <= getLength(v1); ++i) {
        result += (v1.elements[i] * v2.elements[i]);
    }
    return result; // return the value
}
```

Comment: OK, so how do I do what I'm trying to do? Is there any way to do this using a return?

Comment: I'd rather return the double. I must simply because my assignment says I must. Frankly I think that requirement is quite silly. It makes sense for the cross product and transpose where the result is a vector or matrix. But we're supposed to do it the same way for the dot product, even though a dot product merely returns a scalar. I suppose he wants us to check for 0 pointer so we can give an error where the function is called.

Comment: @marshaul several people have told you how to do a quick fix: change `resultPtr = &result;` to `*resultPtr = result;`

Comment: In that case, disregard the final part of my answer. But still, I think your teacher has done too much C.

Comment: @Seth Yeah, I can see that. I've already done the fix (actually I used Etienne's second approach). I was just explaining why I have to do it this way.

Comment: @marshaul: It doesn't make any more sense for vectors or matrices either. Just because it's not a basic type doesn't mean you should pass pointers around. The copy will almost certainly be elided, so you're not wasting anything by doing it. Also, I hope for the sake of whatever class you're talking that you're required to _delete_ those pointers you create.

Comment: Yes, there's a delete statement immediately after the snippet I've shared. :)